# Solr generates 'self intersecting polygon' error inappropriately

Tags: solr, polygon

I am trying to load a 'donut' polygon into Solr.
Solr generates an error which states that the polygon is self-intersecting at an identified point.
The polygon is not self-intersecting at the identified point.
I have loaded the same polygon into the Open Layers test bed at http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/docs/examples/wkt.html
without any issue, therefore I am confident that the definition and structure of the polygon is OK.
I am wondering whether there is a string length config issue which means that solr is not 'seeing' all of my polygon definition, truncating the string at an arbitrary point and then joining whichever point it got up to back to the first point, which could then create a self-intersecting polygon.
Might there be such a max-string-length issue and can anyone suggest where I should look?
Many thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

The limitation would be in your application server, which might limit GET variables to 2048, 4096 or 8192 bytes. You can mitigate this by either changing the configuration for your application server, or using POST to send the request instead of regular GET variables. How this is done (and it might already be doing just that) depends on the Solr library or how you're making the requests.